# extract data from scanned documents c#

Tags: c#, pdf, ocr, text-extraction

I have a PDF file, which contains data that we need to import into a database. 
The file is a pdf scan of printed text. 
The data is structured like this

```
N° Facture : 45526203   
Date : 01/12/2014
Nom de la société : company
```

But this data is not always present on the same regions of the document.So I want a tool or API that can recognize this filelds. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: After reading each line, you can extract numbers, dates or any type you want with `Regex.Match(yourLine,RegexString).Value`

Comment: You can take a look to https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/ocr/ . It allows you to extract text from an image and output it in different format. Then you'll just have to parse the result to finc the informations you need

Answer (score 0):

ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK can do it.
Use the [processTextField](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/apireference/processTextField/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=smm) method to recognize text fields.
 
You can find detailed documentation on [ABBYY's website](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/quick-start/text-fields/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=smm).
If you need any help, please don't hesitate to ask me in comments (I work for ABBYY).